# Как перевести клиенту "резиновая верстка" на англ.язык?

Tags: вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Речь, конечно не о буквальном переводе, а о реальном опыте

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Виды верстки:

**Статический (*Static*)** - использует заданный размер страницы и не изменяется в зависимости от ширины браузера.

**Жидкий, резиновый (*Liquid, Fluid*)** - использует в CSS-стилях относительные единицы измерения вместо фиксированных. Обычно в «**жидких**» макетах шаблона используются **проценты вместо пикселей**.

**Адаптивный (*Adaptive*)** - страницы использует CSS медиа-запросы, чтобы определить ширину браузера и соответствующим образом изменить макет страницы.

**Отзывчивый (*Responsive*)** - для построения шаблона страницы используются как относительные единицы измерения, так и медиа-запросы CSS. Что подразумевает под собой использование преимуществ и «**жидкого**», и **адаптивного макета**.